# I am looking for a content addressing data structure

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to design a data structure that allows efficient extraction of entries from a part of their content.

Let's say I am looking for an entry that matches this:  `[` x **2 3** x x `]`

If `[` 0 **2 3** 4 5 `]` or `[` 3 **2 3** 7 8 `]` are in my data structure, they should be returned by my find function.

I wrote such a data structure where I compare the "pattern" against all entries of the data structure, but of course it takes way too much time.  I have few ideas about how to do this a faster way but they are quite heavy to implement. Does something like this already exists? If not, how would you do this?

Comment: Are you hashing now, or just iterating for every lookup and checking for a particular pattern?

Comment: +1 to this, I was just about to ask something similar :)

Comment: @tinkertim No I am not hashing, it was just an idea I forgot to change the title.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing that comes to mind is to have a hash table for each position in the tuple. For searching you intersect the results for all the positions with a specified value.

Comment: To hash each item is a starting point, but for large answer sets the intersection takes time and consumes memory. Consider also to hash each subset of a specific window size.

Answer (score 4):

Well, a [Suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) could do it in O(1), but it would take a LOT of memory.

Comment: +1. Assuming you have multiple entries, what you really want is called a generalised suffix tree, which is formed by concatenating all the entries together, using distinct (unique) separator symbols between each. Suffix arrays are a (theoretically) slower but much more memory-efficient alternative.

Comment: P.S.: Suffix trees and arrays rock, but they are *hard* to implement. If you can't find an existing implementation, give yourself a solid 2 weeks to try to understand Ukkonnen's or McCreight's original papers on linear-time construction algorithms.

Comment: How specifically does it do it in O(1)? You can retrieve all the entries  containing a particular substring in O(length(substring)), if that's what you mean. I think the given problem does not restrict the known bits to be a single contiguous substring, either.

Comment: I think it does restrict it to a single contiguous substring, but yes, it's not very clear on this. As for O(1) - well, it depends on how you look at it. The Big O in this case depends only on the length of the substring, not the amount of entries in the dictionary.

Comment: Clasically when one talks about searching/sorting algorithms he measures the Big O in respect to the number of entries, not the length of them. From that point of view it's O(1).

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to implement looks a lot like [tuple space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_space).

Comment: Yes it is actually what I want to do but I need I wanted a hint for implementing it. I guess I'll to look at the code! Thanks

Comment: Well I have specific needs but I simplified a bit the problem to ask my question. Available solutions are not exactly what I want, but they are a good start for implementation, I am on it.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the [RETE](http://www.ddj.com/184405218) algorithm. This general problem came up in the AI systems of the 70s; Chapter 14 in [Paradigms of AI Programming](http://norvig.com/paip.html) covers it. (IIRC there's mainly elaborations of starblue's answer and decision trees.)